# is it possible to hide the android emulator buttom back and home bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter to write a page, but now I am facing a problem the android button back/home/menu bar was overlay my UI button. Looks like this:

[image]

I could not click my UI button because the android emulator system menu was overlaying on my UI, what should I do to close the android button bar or make it auto-hide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to hide navigation bar use `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` witch hides both the status bar and the navigation bar.

to show it use  `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);`

or you can wrap the Widget with SafeArea

Comment: I tried right now but it seems did not work. `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);` @Omar Mahmoud